# How can I test if two objects are equal in python?

Tags: python, object, testing, numpy

I have made a function that connects to a twitter api.
This function returns an twitter object. I want to create a testing function that checks if the returned object is really a twitter object. 
So this is my function:

```
def authenticate_twitter_api():
    """Make connection with twitters REST api"""
    try:
        logger.info('Starting Twitter Authentication')
        twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=twitter.OAuth(config.TWITTER_ACCESS_KEY, config.TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET,
                                                     config.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, config.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET))
        print twitter_api
        logger.info("Service has started")
        return twitter_api
    except:
        logger.error("Authentication Error. Could not connect to twitter api service")
```

When i run this function it returns:

```
<twitter.api.Twitter object at 0x7fc751783910>
```

Now, i want to create a testing function, maybe through numpy.testing in order to check if the type is a  object.

```
numpy.testing.assert_equal(actual, desired, err_msg='')

actual = type(authenticate_twitter_api())
desired =<class 'twitter.api.Twitter'>
```

And here is the problem. I can't save an object to 'desired'.

What can i do ?

Answer (score 2):

The desired object you are looking for is `twitter.api.Twitter`, just import it and pass the class the assert_equal.

However, it's more idiomatic to use `isinstance`:

```
from twitter.api import Twitter

if isinstance(authenticate_twitter_api(), Twitter):
    print("It was a Twitter object.")
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

classes are objects themselves in Python. So you can assign your desired variable like this:

```
import twitter
# (...)
desired = twitter.api.Twitter
```